# Text ellipsis isn't working for a column flexbox self

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to set `text-overflow: ellipsis` for a flexbox self.

I only know I have to set the `width` and `overflow: hidden`.

And I expect the text inside the grey block could become abc... if the text is overflowing the div.

I'd tried to remove the flexbox for tag `<a>`, and the ellipsis works.

Unfortunately, I have to put an icon at the top, so I use flex-direction: column to achieve the purpose. 
If I remove the display: flex,  the layout will be gone.

Any suggestions?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  boder: 1px solid blue;
}

a {
  background: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  /* Once I set the <a> as a flex, the-overflow: ellipsis doesn't work  */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}

a:before {
  content: 'icon';
  background: lightblue;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <a>test123tfdsfsdafdsaffdsfdsafsadfest456</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: you didn't say what do want to archive. can you pls explain whats your desired output?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I want to let my text inside the grey block could become text....., if it is overflow.

Comment: please check the answer if it works for you. let me know

Comment: This is just a quick demo bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}

span.text:before {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}

span.gr-bc {
  background: lightgray;
}

a {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}

a:before {
  content: 'icon';
  background: lightblue;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <a>
      <span class="text">
        <span class="gr-bc">
          test123tfdsfsdafdsaffdsfdsafsadfest456
          </span>
  </span>
  </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not exactly correct. The icon should be at the top instead of the left side.

Comment: you wanted it vertically align right? now you are telling me it should be on top. i am confused honestly :/

Comment: Sorry for my expression. I expect the layout display like my example in my question. I just want the text could be an ellipsis

Comment: i have fix it. have a look @RaymondYeh

Comment: Looks great, but I don't think I can revise the element structure. I guess I have to change another way to do this purpose instead of using `flexbox` and `display: column`
Many thanks

Comment: you are wc. please accept this answer as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Flex and ellipsis will not work together in one class. You can apply flex in parent then do ellipsis in child.

As in example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Example of long text which will truncate, 
      resize window to see the effect
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      Button
    </div>
</div>

.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.child {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 7px;
    min-width: 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.button {
    padding: 7px 15px;
    background: #223748;
    color: #fff;
}
```